# Reverse iteration Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my models

One Job can have up to 2 Sides (Front or Back) or only Front

Each Side has multiple Pieces

```
class Job(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    sides = db.relationship('Side', backref=db.backref('job', lazy=True))

class Side(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('job.id'))
    pieces = db.relationship('Piece', backref='side', lazy='select')

class Piece(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    filename_img = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=True)
    side_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('side.id'))
```

Typically I achieve the pieces by this:
Get Job Id -> Side -> Pieces

Example of the populated database

```
Job 1
  Front
    Piece 1
    Piece 2
  Back
    Piece 1

Job 2
  Front
    Piece 3
    Piece 4
  Back
    Piece 3
    Piece 4
```

Sample above shows that Piece 1 has both Front and Back, Piece 2 has only 1 Side which is Front of Job 1. I want to iterate by Pieces instead of Sides in this situation. Is that possible?

The result of what I want would be:

```
Job 1
  Piece 1
    Front
    Back
  Piece 2
    Front
Job 2
  Piece 3
    Front
    Back
  Piece 4
    Front
    Back
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an association table for many-to-many between Side and Piece, then add pieces as a relationship on Job. This *might* work:

```
sides_pieces = db.Table(
    'sides_pieces',
    db.Column('side_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sides.id'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('piece_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pieces.id'), nullable=False)
)

class Job(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    sides = db.relationship('Side', backref=db.backref('job', lazy=True))
    pieces = db.relationship('Piece', backref=db.backref('job', lazy=True))

class Side(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sides'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('jobs.id'))
    pieces = db.relationship('Piece', secondary=sides_pieces, back_populates="sides")

class Piece(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pieces'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('jobs.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    filename_img = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=True)
    sides = db.relationship('Side', secondary=sides_pieces, back_populates="pieces")
```